# selenium - Not able to find input

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to create script which will subscribe to news automatically, but stuck with a problem, `selenium` not able to find email input and submit button. Everytime getting `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

path_to_chromedriver = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)

driver.get('https://dataengweekly.com/')

driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="email"]'))
)

email_input.send_keys("email@test.com")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.subscribe-btn').click()
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note - Your subscription textbox is in a different `iframe`, To work with that `iframe` you need to first switch to that `iframe`.**

Try below code and let me know if you need more clarification -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get('https://dataengweekly.com/')

iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

email_input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='email']")))
action.move_to_element(email_input).click().send_keys("email@test.com").perform()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.subscribe-btn').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: ```iframe``` I forgot about them ) it works, Thanks

Comment: Happy to help :)